# Unable to get proper result using AND operator

Tags: sql

I was wondering what would be the proper query to get a list of the movies where actress X and Y act in

[image: DIAGRAM]

my query(which doesn't work):

```
select m.movie_title
from movie m, actress a, actress_movie am
where m.movie_id = am.movie_id and am.actress_id = a.actress_id AND
a.actress_firstname = 'Jack' and a.actress_firstname = 'Kate' and a.actress_surname = 'Smith' and a.actress_surname = 'Connor'
group by m.movie_title;
```

Comment: The diagram doesnt link to a valid image (any more)

Comment: @MattiasÅslund sorry, fixed now

Answer (score 2):

You are close.  But, the most important thing is to learn to use proper `join` syntax.  That is actually more important than answering this question, which only requires a `having` clause:

```
select m.movie_title
from actress_movie am join
     movie m
     on m.movie_id = am.movie_id join
     actress a
     on am.actress_id = a.actress_id
where (a.actress_firstname = 'Jack' and a.actress_surname = 'Connor') or
      (a.actress_firstname = 'Kate' and a.actress_surname = 'Smith')
group by m.movie_title
having count(distinct am.actress_id) = 2;
```

As a note:  it seems really strange to have a table labelled "actress".  Separating thespians in a database based on gender seems like a poor data model.

Comment: would adding     having count(distinct am.actress_id) = 2; fix the problem then?

Comment: @J.Doe . . . In the query in your question?  Not at all.  The `where` clause will filter out all rows.